# issues with apostrophes in dataTables in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a dataTable which has a good amount of data in it.

In certain columns, there is an apostrophe in the cell.

e.g. "Jack's Pot"

However, when I try to get this data as such:

```
var originalFinalShowsTable = Session["finalShowsTable"] as DataTable;

            var finalShowsTable = new DataTable();

            if (originalFinalShowsTable != null)
            {
                finalShowsTable = originalFinalShowsTable.Clone();
            }

            foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvShows.Rows)
            {
                if (gvr.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    if (((CheckBox) gvr.FindControl("cbSelect")).Checked)
                    {
                        DataRow dr = finalShowsTable.NewRow();

                        for (int i = 0; i < gvr.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
                        {
                            dr[i] = gvr.Cells[i + 1].Text;
                        }

                        finalShowsTable.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }
                }
            }
```

"Jack's Pot" turns into a "Jack&#39;s Pot".

How do I go about avoiding this?

I have seen the same occurring with spaces (&nbsp;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HttpUtility.HtmlDecode Method

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode(v=vs.100).aspx